# make causes core dump when entering an existing container

Tags: compilation, docker

In vagrant vm, I execute:

```
docker exec -it container-id /bin/bash

root@297f6e974824:~$ make

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What could cause this segmentation fault?

As I use docker run to enter:

```
docker run --name cc-122711 -P -v /home/vagrant/mm:/home -ti --cap-add NET_ADMIN --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --device /dev/fuse cc /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --system

root@c9f7f3ed6d33:~$ make

make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. ---it works fine.
```

As a workaround, I need docker run to generate new container every time for the compile env.

I reinstalled make 4.1 version(also 4.0),

sh build.sh,

linking make...
done

bash-4.3# pwd
/home/tools/make-4.1

bash-4.3# ./make

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

bash-4.3# ldd make

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff0c9fe000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f729f088000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f729ecea000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f729f28c000)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a good enough [core(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) file (this means that the limit given thru [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) is large enough), you could run the

```
file core
```

command (see [file(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html)...), it is likely to give you the name of the executable which has crashed to give you that core dump.

Apparently, the  `core` file comes from `make` itself. This is unusual (you could fill a bug report). Please show the relevant `Makefile`. Perhaps you have a `libc` mismatch between the container and the `make` binary, or perhaps the `make` binary is corrupted. Try `ldd make` and `make --version`. You could also try to download the source code of [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make) and compile it yourself (GNU make can be built *without* `make`)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your quick answers,~$ file core.43
core.43: ELF 64-bit LSB core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from 'make'

Comment: @feicheng: this should go into your question, not as a comment to some answer